# AngularJs Application - several browser tabs

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm developping an application in AngularJS, here is the context:

- I use OAuth2 and store the token in the localStorage, and in a variable
- Each time the token is nearly expired I refresh the token in the variable, then update the localStorage token

I'm facing a problem:

- If I open a new browser tab with the same application (ctrl + click on a link), the 2 application are both refreshing the token and one of them get deconnected

Here is my question:

- What is the best way to handle several angularjs application in the same browser, using the same localStorage token ?

The solution that I imagined is to generate an unique id when the application starts (the current timestamp + random value), and each tab is identified with that id. The problem is that I would have concurrency on localStorage, if 2 applications read/write at the same time, they may write over the data written by another one.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to not wait for the token to expire. But a random amount of time before it expires (a number which you could generate when starting the app for example).

Then, when one of the apps reaches that time point, it requests a new token from the server and stores it in localStorage (as well as updates the $http header or whatever you are using).

Your app should also listen for changes in localStorage, like this, the other tab will be notified that a new token is available and should update its variable as well as the $http header (or again whatever you are using).

make sure that when making your randomise function, you make sure the time difference is significant (not a couple of seconds), otherwise you could still be requesting 2 tokens because the other tab is still awaiting response.

Comment: I wrote 'nearly expired', to detail, I refresh when i reach 80% of the expired_time. The problem isn't the generation of an ID, but the fact that if I store in localStorage the list of the current IDs of the same application, i have to parse the localStorage variable i use, then add an id, then store it. During this time, another tab may have done the same thing, and so the ID of the first tab will be erased (Concurrency). The real pb is the concurrency on localStorage.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you need this unique ID (maybe I'm missing the picture). When using a random time offset from the expiration time, you don't necessary need to store this in localStorage. Only the actual expiration time, so that all your apps can calculate their offset. (and store this in a variable, not localStorage).

Comment: The problem is to know if the token has been updated. If we have only 1 application, there is not problem. If we have 2 applications (2 tabs open), they are both updating the localStorage variable which contains the token. Identifying the applications with an ID would allow to know if another tab has updated the ID. In the current code, both will refresh. What i want is one refresh the token, and the others don't, but may try in 80% * expire_time to update it again.

Comment: With different updating times for your tokens (which is unique for each application), when you listen on localStorage changes, the other tabs will be notified if a new token is available in localStorage. The other tabs will only 'read' this token. Which ever tab has the biggest offset to the expiration time, will request a new token first, he will then update the token and its expiration time in the localStorage. The other tabs will be notified, update their internal token (variable or something) and recalculate their expiration time (based on their unique offset).

Comment: It will always be the tab with the biggest offset that is responsible for updating the token in localStorage. If that tab gets close before updating the token, the next one will automatically take over this task. The other tabs don't need to know who will be responsible for updating the tokens. They just all assume they will be updating their token in x time. But once one tab updates the token, they will all be notified and their token aswel as their expiration time will be updated.

Comment: It's more a trick than a real solution. There is no guarantee of no concurrency. For example, if you open 2 tabs at the SAME TIME, concurrency problem if the expire time is the same, and if you randomize the moment you refresh, you may have a chance to have the 2 applications updating at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96423/discussion-between-wout-de-rooms-and-pierre-emmanuel-lallemant).